# Contributing to Babel or Polyglossia language support

Tags: luatex, babel, languages, polyglossia

I want to contribute language support for Babel or Polyglossia, so that I can type in my native language **and** use LuaTex or LuaLaTeX. Lithuanian support at the moment is using L7x font encoding and if I try to use it as it is, it gives me an error.

```
! LaTeX Error: Encoding scheme `L7x' unknown.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...
```

This is the minimal working example (compile with `lualatex`):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec,luatextra}
\usepackage[lithuanian]{babel}

\begin{document}
Hello world ąžerty
\end{document}
```

So, I want to contribute to the babel Lithuanian language support by porting the required parts for LuaLaTeX, but do not have the know how yet.

**Question:** What should I be aware before I start and where should I start? Or would it be easier to start playing with Polyglossia? What is its status on LuaTeX right now?

---

**P.S** I am aware of the new babel [maintainer](http://www.tex-tipografia.com/babel_news.html) but under his provided link there is no Lithuanian language directory. However, there is a [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/language/lithuanian/tex/generic) entry, but I have no idea about it's structure.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [mailing list for TeX and hyphenation patterns](https://www.tug.org/mailman/listinfo/tex-hyphen). This is a good starting point for *anything* TeX-and-language-related.

For `babel` you could file a [bug report](http://latex-project.org/bugs.html) with the LaTeX project.

For `polyglossia` you could also file an [issue](https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues) with the current maintainer.

Comment: Do you know if the polyglossia is currently maintained, because I saw the most recent commits date bake to almost half a year...

Comment: @gns-ank: I know of no other maintainer.