# Create an alphabet package that works like greek letters

Tags: macros, typography, package-writing, letters, alphabet

Some friends and I have been using LaTeX for some years and, at College, we have created some new letters to use with math (it was kind of a joke because we were constantly saying there were few letters available). And we want to port them into LaTeX.

We have all of them drawn on iPad with their lowercase and uppercase forms, and we can easily turn them into svg (which I think should be the best in this case?) or font file.

They're 26 letters (as in the Latin alphabet, at least for Portuguese), and a way of doing this is by mapping each letter to a Latin letter. But we don't intend to make this work as a font. We want to work as `\pi`, or `\Omega`.

I'm not really sure where to start. I have some knowledge of working with custom packages but nothing related to new symbols. Can somebody help?

Comment: Have you seen https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/219959 ?

Comment: svg isn't so useful, a font or pdf would be better or if you don't mind them being bitmaps (perhaps they were created as bitmaps?) save as jpg

Comment: includegraphics →[macros - How to add a custom symbol to LaTeX? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13594/how-to-add-a-custom-symbol-to-latex)

Comment: If you have `svg` files you can [use `\includesvg`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/523685/48973) instead of `\includegraphics`. Though you can probably convert to `pdf` just as easily as to `svg`?

Comment: I might be able to get the `svg` easily. Can I store it inside the (or another linked to it) `.sty`? Because I may want people not to have to download a couple of files.